# a continuous function $f:(0,2)\to (0,2)$ and $A\subseteq (0,2)$ such that $f$ is not differentiable on $A$

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone give an example of a continuous function $f:(0,2)\to (0,2)$  and $A\subseteq (0,2)$ such that $f$ is not differentiable on $A$ but on $(0,2)\setminus A$, where $A$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Think about a function piecewise linear, made of triangles (height 1) getting closer and closer to $0$, such that the base of the $n$-th triangle is of size $1/n$. It is not differentiable at any of the 3 points defining each triangle.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $1/n^2$.

Comment: i thought about something like that but was unable to give a mathematical rigor

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalizing the "countably many increasingly narrow triangles" construction hinted above in the comments, take $f$ defined as follows:

- for every integer $n \geq 1$, set $x_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}1-\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$ and $y_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\frac{x_{n+1}+x_n}{2}$
- define $f$, piecewise affine, by 
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  \forall x\in(x_1, 2),\qquad& f(x)=0 \\
  \end{align*}
  $$
  and, for all $n\geq 1$,
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  & f(x_n)=f(x_{n+1})=0, \quad f(y_n)=1\\
  \forall x\in(x_{n+1},x_n),\quad &f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{x-x_{n+1}}{y_n-x_{n+1}} &\text{ if } x\in(x_{n+1},y_n)\\
  \frac{x_n-x}{x_n-y_n} &\text{ if } x\in(y_n,x_n)
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  $$

Note that $f$ is indeed

- defined on $(0,2)$
- continuous (it is on $[x_1,2)$, on each $[x_{n+1},y_n]$ and $[y_n,x_n]$, and the values at each $x_n$ and $y_n$ is defined to glue them together well)
- differentiable on every $[x_{n+1},y_n]$ and $[y_n,x_n]$, and on $[x_1,2)$, i.e. on $(0,2)\setminus(\{x_n\}\cup\{y_n\})_{n\geq 1}$;
- **not** differentiable at any $x_n$ nor $y_n$.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite countably infinite sets is $A=\{\frac 1n|n \in \Bbb N\}$, but it is easier to flip it.  Lets define $g(x)= \begin {cases}0& 0 \lt x \le 1\\1&2-\frac 1{2n-1}\lt x \le 2-\frac 1{2n}\\-1&2-\frac 1{2n}\lt x \le 2-\frac 1{2n+1} \end {cases}$

where for us $\Bbb N$ starts at $1$.  Now let $f(x)=\frac 14+\int_0^x g(t)dt$  You have a slope discontinuity at a countable infinity of points.  The integral guarantees continuity (why?)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the "ruler" function, $g$, whose value at $x = \frac{2n+1}{2^p}$ is $\frac{1}{2^p}$, where $n$ is any integer and $p$ is any nonnegative integer.

$g$ is discontinuous at the "2-rational" points (the ones of the form $\frac{2n+1}{2^p}$), and continuous elsewhere.

Convolve $g$ with the "box" function $x \mapsto b(x)$ that's $1$ for $x \in [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$, and zero elsewhere. The result $h = g \star b$ will be continuous everywhere and differentiable at precisely the points where $g$ was continuous, so $h$ is an example of the kind you wanted.